# neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.linuxbridge.agent.linuxbridge_neutron_agent [-] Interface for physical network provider does not exist

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I install controller node and compute node in one server. when I install the compute service:

I use `neutron agent-list` shows nothing:

```
[root@controller ~]# neutron agent-list
neutron CLI is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use openstack CLI instead.
```

I also tried use `openstack network agent list`, still shows nothing.

I check the `/var/log/neutron/linuxbridge-agent.log`, find it say`Interface ifcfg-enp2s0f0 for physical network provider does not exist.`:

```
vim /var/log/neutron/linuxbridge-agent.log

2017-12-07 23:04:08.374 12766 INFO neutron.common.config [-] Logging enabled!
2017-12-07 23:04:08.375 12766 INFO neutron.common.config [-] /usr/bin/neutron-linuxbridge-agent version 10.0.0
2017-12-07 23:04:08.375 12766 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.linuxbridge.agent.linuxbridge_neutron_agent [-] Interface mappings: {'provider': 'ifcfg-enp2s0f0'}
2017-12-07 23:04:08.375 12766 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.linuxbridge.agent.linuxbridge_neutron_agent [-] Bridge mappings: {}
2017-12-07 23:04:08.382 12766 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.linuxbridge.agent.linuxbridge_neutron_agent [-] Interface ifcfg-enp2s0f0 for physical network provider does not exist. Agent terminated!
```

I use `vim /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/linuxbridge_agent.ini` check my linuxbridge_agent.ini:

```
[linux_bridge]
physical_interface_mappings = provider:ifcfg-enp2s0f0

[securitygroup]
enable_security_group = True
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.IptablesFirewallDriver

[vxlan]
enable_vxlan = True
local_ip = 10.1.1.120
l2_population = True
```

But however in my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`， I have `ifcfg-enp2s0f0` and `ifcfg-enp2s0f1` network-interfaces.

in my `ifcfg-enp2s0f0`:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="no"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp2s0f0"
UUID="2748d036-2377-4d8d-9753-52873fe03d3d"
DEVICE="enp2s0f0"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR="100.35.202.1"
PREFIX="29"
IPADDR1="100.35.202.2"
PREFIX1="29"
IPADDR2="100.35.202.3"
PREFIX2="29"
IPADDR3="100.35.202.4"
PREFIX3="29"
IPADDR4="100.35.202.5"
PREFIX4="29"
GATEWAY="100.35.202.6"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_PRIVACY="no"
```

in my `ifcfg-enp2s0f1`:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp2s0f1
UUID=098161a9-4bae-4ff2-a768-eeaada509507
DEVICE=enp2s0f1
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=10.1.1.120
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
~
```

I don't know whtere is the issue, some friend can help me about it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bernd Bausch, he tell me the issue is:

```
physical_interface_mappings = provider:ifcfg-enp2s0f0
```

My network-interface name is `enp2s0f0`, not the `ifcfg-enp2s0f0`.